# Excel VBA - Automatic Creation of Hyperlinks occurring on blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using MS Office 2016 Pro Plus.  I have a Macro enabled workbook which has a Power Query (PQ) connection to a sharepoint list.  The below code was designed to automatically refresh / create Hyperlinks based on the values within the cells in Columns A and B so in theory, I can click the links and they take me to the list SP list item i'm interested in.

The code below works, in the sense that whenever I refresh the PQ connection, it creates the links BUT (and here's the issue)... if the number of list items reduces, it **still** tries to create hyperlinks in columns A and B in the cells that were previously filled in... but I don't want it to.  See example picture below and subsequent code:

Issue Example:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim cell As Range
Dim tmp As String
If Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each cell In Target
    If cell.Column = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        tmp = cell.Value2
        cell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=Cells(cell.Row, 1), _
            Address:="<<My Shareopint List URL1>>/EditForm.aspx?ID=" & tmp, _
            TextToDisplay:=tmp
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
Next cell

For Each cell In Target
    If cell.Column = 2 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        tmp = cell.Value2
        cell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=Cells(cell.Row, 2), _
            Address:="<<My Shareopint list URL2>>" & tmp, _
            TextToDisplay:=tmp
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
Next cell

Columns("A:B").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 10

End Sub
```

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test each cell contains a value before adding the link:

```
    If cell.Column = 1 And Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Worked perfectly.